# Prove that $\sigma$ equals an orthogonal transformation and a transformation of scalar multiplicalion.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is an Euclidean space with $\dim V\ge2$ . The linear transformation $\sigma$ on $V$ turns every two mutually orthogonal non-zero vectors to two mutually orthogonal non-zero vectors. Prove that $\sigma$ equals an orthogonal transformation and a transformation of scalar multiplicalion. i.e $\sigma=TK $ which $T$ is an orthogonal transformation and $K$ is a transformation of scalar multiplicalion.

---

I tried this. For an arbitrary orthonormal basis , $\sigma$  turns it to an orthogonal basis. Transform the basis to an orthonormal basis. The transform between two orthonormal basis is orthogonal transformation. But I still need to proof the vectors in orthogonal basis have same length to get transformation of scalar multiplicalion. How to make this.

Comment: European space? You mean Euclidean?

Comment: I don't know why it come to my mind...